# reconocer el carácter bullet ( • ) en un if

Tags: javascript

Buen día , mi problema es que obtengo información con javascript , me mandan una cadena que viene con varios • que corresponde a una actividad, hice un ciclo para leer elemento por elemento de la cadena para que cuando encuentre este símbolo • corte la cadena y continúe.
el problema es que al parece mi `if` no reconoce el símbolo al leerlo y lo deja pasar , ya probé con *, . etc y funciona pero con ese **bullet** no logro hacerlo.
como podría indicarle al `if` para que lo reconozca

mi `if` es algo así:

```js
function()
{
    var v1 = parseInt($(this).attr("ows_Numero"));
    var v2 = String($(this).attr("ows_Responsable"));if (v2 == 'undefined'){v2 ='';}
    var v3 = String($(this).attr("ows_Actividad"));if (v3 == 'undefined'){v3 ='';}
 
    var text = "";     
    var longitud = v3.length;   
    var temporal = ""; 
   
    for (i = 0; i < longitud; i++) { 
      
  if((cadena[i] == '•') ||( cadena [i] == '.')){
      text = '<br>' + cadena[i];
      console.log(cadena[i]);   
      temporal = temporal + text;
  }else{
             text = cadena[i];
      console.log(cadena[i]);
      temporal = temporal + text;
  }    
 }
     
 text = temporal;
```

Comment: pon tu codigo completo no podemos simplemente adivinar!

Comment: Con estos símbolos raros, en mi experiencia lo mejor es coger el mensaje que te envían, hacer cortar y pegar y adivinar el valor unicode del símbolo. Puede ser que haya veinte símbolos que se representen exactamente igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir el símbolo en cuestión a su **[Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/es/#sundanese)** equivalente y comparar el valor

```js
const get = () => {
  const ch = '•'.charCodeAt(0);
  
  if(ch == 8226)
    alert(ch)
  else
    alert('No es bullet')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="get()">Obtener Valor</button>
</div>
```

Aún así trata con mucho cuidado tu lógica y ten en cuenta el comentario de **SJuan76**!

Nos comentas que tal te va

Comment: gracias tu ejemplo fue el que termino por darme la solución, mas abajo coloco cual fue el resultado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la comparación por **código ASCII**, o simplemente usar el `localCompare()` de ese carácter

```
function compareFunction() {
  var str1 = "•";
  var str2 = "•";
  return  str1.localeCompare(str2);
}
```

Retornara 0 si las dos cadenas son iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podría ser comparar el código ASCII de bullet.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
if(cadena[i] === '&#8226')
    alert("ok");
else
    alert("error");
```

Simplemente seria eso. Saludos